# advance function game of life

Tags: c++, arrays, void

I made a function which changes my current status in game of life to the next generation,
working on a 1d array I get some faults for my next generation. My field is just completely reseted so that every cell is dead. I suggest that I still miss the cases of my border fields.
My Question is if there's a easier way to implement the next Generation and give me a helping hand.

```
void GameOfLife::advance(){
int alive;
int dead;
int row,col;
for(int x = 0; x<=mapsize;x++){
                        SpielfeldNextGen[x]=Spielfeld[x];
                    }
for(row = 0; row<=mapheight-1;row++){
    for(col = 0; col<=mapwidth-1;col++){
        if (Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row]               == '0'){
            if(Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row+1]          == '0'){alive+=1;}
            if(Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row-1]          == '0'){alive+=1;}
            if(Spielfeld[(mapwidth*col+row)-mapwidth]   == '0'){alive+=1;}
            if(Spielfeld[((mapwidth*col+row)-mapwidth)-1] == '0'){alive+=1;}
            if(Spielfeld[((mapwidth*col+row)-mapwidth)+1] == '0'){alive+=1;}
            if(Spielfeld[((mapwidth*col+row)+mapwidth)+1] == '0'){alive+=1;}
            if(Spielfeld[((mapwidth*col+row)+mapwidth)-1] == '0'){alive+=1;}
            if(Spielfeld[((mapwidth*col+row)+mapwidth)]   == '0'){alive+=1;}
        }

        else{
        if(Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row+1]            == '0'){dead+=1;}
        if(Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row-1]            == '0'){dead+=1;}
        if(Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row-mapwidth] == '0'){dead+=1;}
        if(Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row-mapwidth-1]   == '0'){dead+=1;}
        if(Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row-mapwidth+1]   == '0'){dead+=1;}
        if(Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row+mapwidth+1]   == '0'){dead+=1;}
        if(Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row+mapwidth-1]   == '0'){dead+=1;}
        if(Spielfeld[mapwidth*col+row+mapwidth]     == '0'){dead+=1;}
        }
        if((alive<2)||(alive>3)){SpielfeldNextGen[mapwidth*col+row]='0';}
                                            else SpielfeldNextGen[mapwidth*col+row]='.';
        if(dead==3){SpielfeldNextGen[mapwidth*col+row]='.';}
                                            else SpielfeldNextGen[mapwidth*col+row]='0';
        alive=0;
        dead=0;
    }
}
for(int x = 0;x<=mapsize;x++){
                            Spielfeld[x]=SpielfeldNextGen[x];
                        }
}
```

Comment: This looks like better being posted at [CodeReview SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: what is `next Generation` ?

Comment: Perhaps explain the rules of the 'Game of Life' because some reader wouldn't know and the specific details are important

Comment: please excuse the missing rules  
    1: Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.
   2: Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
   3: Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overcrowding.
   4: Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

Comment: A first step: initialise `alive` and `dead` to zero.